# pyqt file to exe file by py2exe runtime error:this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, py2exe

I used the cv2 package in my python files. before convert file to exe file by py2exe, it can work. But when converted exe file, I get the Runtime Error! This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. this is my file.
test1.py

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from test2 import opencv_test
import os
import sys 

QTextCodec.setCodecForTr(QTextCodec.codecForName("utf8"))
class BaseInfo(QWidget):
def __init__(self,parent=None): 
    super(BaseInfo,self).__init__(parent)
    self.filename = "C:\pythontest\certphoto\\test1.png"
    self.imageLabel=QLabel()  
    self.imageLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored,QSizePolicy.Ignored)  
    image = QPixmap(self)
    if image.load(self.filename):
       pixmap_resized = image.scaled(519, 692, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
       self.imageLabel.setPixmap(pixmap_resized) 
       self.resize(519,692) 

    hLayout=QHBoxLayout()
    hLayout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)
    OKPushButton=QPushButton(self.tr("change"))   
    bottomLayout=QHBoxLayout()  
    bottomLayout.addStretch() 
    bottomLayout.addWidget(OKPushButton)  
    self.connect(OKPushButton,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.extpic)

    mainLayout=QGridLayout(self)  
    mainLayout.setMargin(15)  
    mainLayout.setSpacing(10)  
    mainLayout.addLayout(hLayout,0,0)  
    mainLayout.addLayout(bottomLayout,1,0)

def extpic(self):
    cv_test = opencv_test()
    cv_test.change(str(self.filename)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form=BaseInfo()
form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

test2.py

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from cv2 import cvtColor
class opencv_test:
    def change(self,filename):
        print filename
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        img = cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.imwrite("C:\\pythontest\\certphoto\\output\\what.jpg",img)
```

convert to exe file setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

py2exe_options = {
     "includes": ["sip","numpy","cv2"],
     "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll",],
     "compressed": 1,
     "optimize": 2,
     "ascii": 0,
     "bundle_files": 1,
    }

setup(
   name = 'PyQt Demo',
   version = '1.0',
   windows = [r'C:\pythontest\testphoto\test1.py'],
   zipfile = None,
   options = {'py2exe': py2exe_options}
  )
```

error message:

[image]